# Scroll to a particular element w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a long list of nested divs.  I am passing the ID of a particular element (actually a paragraph element) on the querystring and opening its div and parent onload.  However, the list is so long, sometimes the element that opens is hidden below the bottom of the window.

**How do I automatically scroll the user's browser window so that the displayed element is at the top of the screen?**

You probably don't need this, but for the record... my list looks like this:

```
<div id="div1">
    <p id="1"></p>   
    <div>stuff</div>
    <p id="2"></p>   
    <div>stuff</div>
    <p id="3"></p>   
    <div>stuff</div>
</div>
...
<div id="divN">
    <p id="997"></p>   
    <div>stuff</div>
    <p id="998"></p>   
    <div>stuff</div>
    <p id="999"></p>   
    <div>stuff</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not valid to start your IDs with a number.

Comment: Yea yea... that's not the actual code.  :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView) function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#divN').get(0).scrollIntoView();
});
```

Comment: +1 on this answer, but with the caveat that it does not scroll if the target is already in view. @Russ - This is widely supported to my knowledge.

Comment: @Russ: I don't think so, otherwise it would be a pretty nice feature. But I really think it sounds to good to be true. Resig & jQuery core team would have implemented it if its crossbrowser.

Comment: @Russ although it is non-standard it does seem to work in at least IE 5.5+ Firefox, Chrome and Safari. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t23

Answer (score 6):

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document.body).scrollTop($('#divN').offset().top);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is by using **[Ariel Flesler's scrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)**. I've used it a few times before and it is small, lightweight and works very well.